# How to Count Occurrences in a Column while including another column with unique values with SQL?

Tags: sql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have a table of customers:

| id | order |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 25 |
| 1 | 25 |
| 2 | 23 |
| 3 | 24 |
| 4 | 25 |

I want to query for all customers, and an additional column that counts how many customers are of the same order number:

| id | order | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 25 | 3 |
| 1 | 25 | 3 |
| 2 | 21 | 1 |
| 3 | 25 | 3 |
| 4 | 22 | 1 |

I have tried this syntax

```sql
SELECT A.id, A.0rder, B.cnt
  FROM Customers  A
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Order, count(Order) as cnt
      FROM Customers 
      GROUP BY Order
  ) B ON A.Order = B.Order
```

and ran into this error. 'Error saving the Query field.Old style JOIN (ANSI JOINs) syntax is not allowed. Please use standard syntax.'

Comment: SELECT A.id, A.0rder, B.cnt FROM Customers A, (SELECT Order, count(Order) as cnt FROM Customers GROUP BY Order) B ON A.Order = B.Order;

I didn't look over your SQL query other than the comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your query is that your column named `order` is also a keyword eg `ORDER BY`. You may resolve this by using a table alias as shown below:

```
SELECT 
    A.id, A.order, 
    B.cnt 
FROM 
    Customers A 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT b.Order, count(b.Order) as cnt 
  FROM Customers b GROUP BY b.Order
) B ON A.Order = B.Order;
```

| id | order | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 25 | 3 |
| 1 | 25 | 3 |
| 2 | 23 | 1 |
| 3 | 24 | 1 |
| 4 | 25 | 3 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iPfq7BXttW6VZPyth8RepS/2)

You may also use a window function COUNT with a partition on the order column or use a correlated query to achieve this. Both approaches have been included below.

**Query #1 - Window Functions**

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.order) as count
FROM
    my_table t1
ORDER BY 
    t1.id;
```

| id | order | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 25 | 3 |
| 1 | 25 | 3 |
| 2 | 23 | 1 |
| 3 | 24 | 1 |
| 4 | 25 | 3 |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(1) FROM my_table t2 WHERE t2.order=t1.order
    ) as count
FROM
    my_table t1
ORDER BY 
    t1.id;
```

| id | order | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 25 | 3 |
| 1 | 25 | 3 |
| 2 | 23 | 1 |
| 3 | 24 | 1 |
| 4 | 25 | 3 |

---

[View Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iPfq7BXttW6VZPyth8RepS/1)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you @ggordon!!! Query #1 - Window Functions did the trick.

Comment: Great! Please upvote and mark this as the answer so that other stackoverflow users with similar issues will find it useful